# What is better: a single BAO or multiple BAOs

Tags: c, opengl

So I'm currently learning OpenGL, and while working through some of the tutorials, I've noticed that most of them create multiple buffer-array-objects (BAO) for the vertex-positions, normal-vectors and uv-coordinates. But there is also the option to just create a single BAO, where each element includes all the necessary information about a single vector. So what's the "good" or rather "recommended" way of doing things? Create multiple ones or just a single one?

Comment: There is no such thing as a "buffer-array-object" in OpenGL. Perhaps you mean "vertex-array-object"?

Comment: I mean the buffers, containing information about a vertex, which you can then attach to a VAO. Like say the position of the vertices or the normal-vectors.

Comment: That's just a [buffer object](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Buffer_Object). It's fundamentally no different from any other buffer object. So, are you asking about interleaved vertex formats vs. independent arrays or something else?

Comment: Those are usually called VBOs (vertex buffer objects).

Comment: In the end, I just want to know what's right and wrong. Because many create multiple buffer-objects, which seems kind of unnecessary to me.

Comment: "*What's right and wrong*" about what? We have yet to establish what you're asking about. The specific details of the different cases under consideration. Please add those details to the question itself.

Comment: Creating a VAO and attaching all vertex-positions, normal-vectors, and uv-coordinates to it in C. When creating a buffer for each attribute, it just creates the problem of having to keep track of the different array, while one single buffer containing everything makes the whole thing a lot more simplistic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Buffer Object - OpenGL Wiki](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Buffer_Object) (recommended reading):

> Buffer Object Usage
>   Buffer objects are general purpose memory storage blocks allocated by OpenGL. They are intended to be used in a great many ways. To give the implementation great flexibility in exactly what a particular buffer object's data store will be, so as to better optimize performance, the user is required to give usage hints. These provide a general description as to how exactly the user will be using the buffer object.

BO's are shared between the client and the server (in OpenGL terms). How many of them you should use, is entirely up to you.  Your instincts seem to be good however.  You should never optimize before you just get it working.  But after you've had some experience with OpenGL, you'll probably find there are use cases, where a little early optimization can save you a lot of refactoring later on.

I can't help you much with where to draw those lines, but I would say that you should think first, about what and when you intend to render as execution progresses.